# Amazon S3 Securing Static Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web, sign

I'm looking for a combination of policies to access a static website in a S3 bucket only with a certain token/sign string.
I mean, is it possibile to make the static website not readable by everyone by default but temporary accessible with something like `http://mybucket.s3-website-location.amazonaws.com/myfolder/index.html?sign=XXXXX`?
With this call you should also have access to all the tree in the "myfolder" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this for a single URL at a time, using a signed S3 URL with an expiration time. There is no way to create a signature that can be appended to any of a group of URLs that will make them all work with the signature, but not work without it.

Sorry.

However, this is fairly easy to do with an actual website as a front end. You'd have to code the website to redirect every request to a signed URL specific to that object. To do that, you'd need an EC2 instance that runs the code you write. But as of now, S3 doesn't have a way to do this all by itself.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think its possible - think about how you would do that on a regular website, you would need to read the querystring and then do some sort of lookup/logic to determine if the token was valid, i.e. you need to do some server-side processing to carry out that logic.

Once you need to add server-side logic you are no longer have a 'static' website (even though ultimately you may be serving up static pages). S3 may not be the right solution for you in this case.

From aws: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

> You can host a static website on Amazon S3. On a static website, individual web pages include static content. They may also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. **Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.**