# Statically host a website on S3 that can only be read by authenticated AWS users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-iam

I would like to statically host a website using amazon s3, but configure permissions so that only authenticated users can access the website on their browser.

Permissions configured

```
s3Bucket:
  any authenticated AWS user has object read and permission read access.
  no permissions granted to "everyone"
All Objects:
  any authenticated AWS user has object read and permission read access.
  no permissions granted to "everyone"
```

Going to the site returns a **403 Forbidden** status (code: AccessDenied, message: AccessDenied)

I'm using the aws cli to authenticate my IAM user. Any ideas around why I'm still getting a forbidden, or suggestions on what else I should try/check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your browser to access your secured content, it needs to send along the credentials needed to prove to S3 that it's authenticated. Your browser won't do this for a normal website, because it's not designed to.

Authenticating your IAM user using the CLI will only affect the CLI, it won't affect browsers on your computer.

The only way to accomplish what you're looking for is to host your website on a server instead (for example, EC2). S3 won't do what you want it to do.

Not much has changed from 2013 in this regard: [Amazon S3 Securing Static Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240636/amazon-s3-securing-static-website)